# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

What is this warning? 
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt

my use [this](https://ufile.io/nhu4j) Database.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','new_schema');
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$query = "select * from csv where rgion = ? and city like ?";
$stmt->prepare($query);
$reg = 11;
$ci = '%dg%';
$stmt->bind_param('si',$ci,$reg);
$stmt->bind_result($country,$city,$accentcity,$region,$population,$latitude,$longitude);
$stmt->execute();
echo "<table border='1'>";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$country</td>";
    echo "<td>$city</td>";
    echo "<td>$accentcity</td>";
    echo "<td>$region</td>";
    echo "<td>$population</td>";
    echo "<td>$latitude</td>";
    echo "<td>$longitude</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have wrong sequence of type in bind_param (first place you have an int, second a string) so respect type an sequence

```
  $query = "select * from csv where rgion = ? and city like ?)";
  $stmt->prepare($query);
  $reg = 11;
  $ci = '%dg%';
  $stmt->bind_param('is',$reg, $ci);
```

and as  a suggestion try avoid the wildchar in string this way

```
  $query = "select * from csv where rgion = ? and city like concat('%',?,'%')";
  $stmt->prepare($query);
  $reg = 11;
  $ci = 'dg';
  $stmt->bind_param('is',$reg, $ci);
```

Comment: you have tried  with the concat  suggestion too  (and the string without %)??

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code again did not work!!
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): invalid object or resource mysqli_stmt

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','new_schema');
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$query = "select * from csv where rgion = ? and city like ?";
$stmt->prepare($query);
$reg = 11;
$ci = '%dg%';
$stmt->bind_param('is',$reg,$ci);
$stmt->bind_result($country,$city,$accentcity,$region,$population,$latitude,$longitude);
$stmt->execute();
echo "<table border='1'>";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$country</td>";
    echo "<td>$city</td>";
    echo "<td>$accentcity</td>";
    echo "<td>$region</td>";
    echo "<td>$population</td>";
    echo "<td>$latitude</td>";
    echo "<td>$longitude</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

> you have tried with the concat suggestion too (and the string without
>   %)??

I also tested it again warns

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','new_schema');
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$query = "select * from csv where rgion = ? and city like concat('%',?,'%')";
$stmt->prepare($query);
$reg = 11;
$ci = 'dg';
$stmt->bind_param('is',$reg,$ci);
$stmt->bind_result($country,$city,$accentcity,$region,$population,$latitude,$longitude);
$stmt->execute();
echo "<table border='1'>";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$country</td>";
    echo "<td>$city</td>";
    echo "<td>$accentcity</td>";
    echo "<td>$region</td>";
    echo "<td>$population</td>";
    echo "<td>$latitude</td>";
    echo "<td>$longitude</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```